# Output XML nodes that use a XMLNS in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I was given this code from a client but I'm not sure how to do a `<xsl:for-each>` to loop over these because of the `a:` xmlns.

Here is the code

```
<nodes xmlns:a="http://www.test.com/api/">
    <a:node>
        <a:Number>T123123</a:Number>
        <a:Url>http://www.link2.com/</a:Url>
    </a:node>
    <a:node>
        <a:Number>345345</a:Number>
        <a:Url>http://www.link2.com/</a:Url>
    </a:node>
    <a:node>
        <a:Number>456456456</a:Number>
        <a:Url i:nil="true"/>
    </a:node>
</nodes>
```

I've tried a bunch including the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="nodes/a:node">
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each select="a:nodes/a:node">
```

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Search for "xslt default namespace" and find another 524 answers to this question.

Comment: Good call. I didn't realize it was called a "default namespace" which makes the search easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can use a prefix, you need to first declare the prefix pointing to the corresponding namespace URI :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="http://www.test.com/api/">
```

Namespace prefix in the XSLT can be different from the one in the source XML as long as both mapped to the same URI.

<s>It isn't clear what the context element in your `xsl:for-each` and what the correct XPath expression for it since your attempted XPath doesn't correspond to the sample XML posted, so I can't comment on that part.</s>

Comment: Ahhh I didn't have `xmlns:a="http://www.test.com/api/` declared in the XSL. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out the issue in namespaces... I changed the clients code and forgot to change it in my `for-each` examples. I've updated my question.